# Can someone own multiple death notes?

Tags: death-note

I know from [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/can-a-death-note-have-multiple-owners) that a death note could only belong to one person at a time, but I was wondering if the opposite was true--that one person could own multiple death notes. Could, say, that person go around killing the owners of death notes and stealing them in an effort to do something like own all of the death notes?

Comment: yes. Light had two death notes after Rem died for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently yes, there are rules about how the Death Note works if someone has more than 1. These rules are stated in [How to Use: XXIII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXIII)

> Whenever an individual with ownership of more than two Death Notes loses possession to one of the Death Notes, he will not be able to recognize that Death Note's god of death's appearance or voice anymore. The god of death himself will leave, but all the memory involving that Death Note will remain as long as he maintains ownership of at least one other Death Note.

And in [How to Use: XXXII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XXXII)

> If someone possesses more than one Death Note, by visualizing the victim, then writing down the name in one of the Death Notes and the cause of death in the other, it will take effect. The order however, is unimportant, if you write down the cause of death in one Death Note and afterwards, write the name in the other, it will take effect.

We also see Light owning 2 Death Notes in Episode 25 - *Silence* and in Chapter 58 - *Feelings Within*. while the scenes play out differently in both Light becomes the owner of Rem's Death Note after she has died. in *Death Note: The Last Name* we however never see this as Rem destroys her Death Note in the equivalent scene.

There is however a limit of 6 Death Notes that a single persona can own. This is because only 6 death Notes can be active as it is stated in [How to Use: LII, Point 1](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LII)

> In the event that there are more than 6 Death Notes in the human world, only the first 6 Death Notes that have been delivered to humans will have effect.

One can assume "ownership" will not work unless the Death Note is active, so the 7th Death Note can probably be passed around. But when one of the currently active 6 is removed (destroyed or taken back to the Shinigami Realm), the person currently holding the 7th will become the owner.

Comment: Didn't Light own two for a short while when Misa Misa was in L's custody and Light was preping to go into custody.  I know that the Shinigami had ownership during that time too so it is a little jumbled and I don't remember the exact sequence of events.

Comment: @kaine i was for sure that Rem still owned Misa's Death Note at the time unless your talking about when Light, Rem and Ryuk was swapping around the Death Notes in which case i'm a bit confused too. i'll edit the first paragraph just in case

Comment: I was talking about the swapping.  If I rewatched I could figure it out.

Comment: Didn't Light own two note books when Rem died? He obtained one from his father and one from Rem afaik

Comment: @PeterRaeves your right, i must have been remembering The Last Name where when Rem was dying from having killed L and Watari she also destroyed her own Death Note